# Validating a proposition

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Proposition: For all $k,n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ $s.t$  $n\lt4$  $2{n\choose n}+{n\choose n-1}+...+{n\choose k-(n-2)}=2^n$ for $1\le k\le n-1.$

I understand that this proposition is invalid, so are there ways i can make it valid for certain $k,n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$. Also is it possible to approximate the sum in a big-Oh manner??

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that $2{n\choose n}+{n\choose n-1}+...+{n\choose k-(n-2)}=2^n$ for $1\le k\le n-1$ implies $k=n-1$, because binomial coefficients are positive and ${n\choose n}+{n\choose n-1}+...+{n\choose 0}=2^n$.

Comment: Okay what i'm asking is if the proposition is true for some $k,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ without escaping to the binomial theorem or some other similar theorem i.e can i construct another theorem, lemma, corollary with this proposition and for what $k$ or $n$??